# Get range of 3D object given lowest and highest point and angle

Tags: 3d

How do you get 3D range of object (highlighted in red below) given its lowest (PL) and highest (PH) (x,y,z) coordinates and orientation of object? Image below is a top view of a box.

[image: Top view of object]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way already

[image: Top view of object]

Given:
1)$$H_1 = L\sin(\theta) + W\cos(\theta)$$
2)$$H_2 = L\cos(\theta) + W\sin(\theta)$$
 
Then...

3)$$L = \frac{H_2 - W\sin\theta} {\cos(\theta)}$$

Substitute...
$$H_1 = \frac{H_2-W\sin\theta} {\cos\theta}sin\theta + W\cos\theta$$
$$H_1 = \frac{H_2\sin\theta} {\cos\theta} - \frac{W\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta} + Wcos\theta$$
$$H_1 = \frac{H_2\sin\theta} {\cos\theta} - \frac{W(1-\cos^2\theta)}{\cos\theta} + W\cos\theta$$
$$H_1 = \frac{H_2\sin\theta} {\cos\theta} - \frac{W}{\cos\theta} + W\cos\theta + W\cos\theta$$
$$H_1 = \frac{H_2\sin\theta} {\cos\theta} - W\left(\frac{1}{\cos\theta} + \cos\theta + \cos\theta\right)$$
$$W\left(\frac{1}{\cos\theta} + \cos\theta + \cos\theta\right) = \frac{H_2\sin\theta} {\cos\theta} - H_1$$
$$W = \frac{(H_2\tan\theta - H_1){\frac{1-2\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta}}$$
4)$$W = \frac{(H_2\tan\theta - H_1)\cos\theta}{1-2\cos^2\theta}$$

Since you have W, substitute W of formula 3 to get L.

Once you have L, you can get the points easily.

P.S. This does not apply if angle is 45 degrees.